# container using its maximum width even if text is not that much larger

Tags: html, css

I have a `li` containing a heading and few links. `li` width should be `auto` as per characters in heading and links but maximum width could be 166px. If any line is greater than 166px than there should be word-break.

The problem is when heading is larger and using word-break, `li` still using maximum width which is 166px but its width should be as per words width.

Check the **HTML/CSS** here:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwani007/2q8WS/3/)

Comment: Did you mean Heading in one line and max-width 166px for links and the wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2q8WS/21/)

**CSS** that requires amendment (rest everything remains same) :

```
ul {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:20%; /*add this to have a clear picture, optional but recommended*/

}

span, a {
    display: block;
    font: 14px arial;
    word-break: break-all; /*add this*/
    max-width:80% ;
}
```

What you missed here is, that, `ul` is the parent and you are setting `max` property on the child `li`...to do it that way(though i wont suggest it)...you should set a `width` on the `ul` too!!

Additionally, to break big words, use `word-break: break-all;` property...its quiet handy... [Read More Here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/)

Comment: looks promising! let me check it once. Thanks a lot dude :)

Answer (score 0):

Use  **min-width**  instead of max-width.
That will solve your purpose of keeping the width 166px too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
max-width: 166px
```

from the li elements and if you want some minimum width add

```
min-width: 100px
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/2q8WS/4/

Comment: Thanks Raunak for your suggestion but in any case **li** width should not exceed more than 166px. Using min-width it will be greater than 166px because heading is bit larger than 166px.

Comment: This is not possible because max-width will force it to be 166px even if word length is less or greater

Comment: You can have one of these two things so you have trade between these :)